# iPhone X not displaying selection screen from start

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, iphone-x

I am trying to set a selection image to UITabbar item,

Here is the screenshot.

It works fine on all other screens except iPhoneX[image]

How can i make it appear from y = 0

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about `selectionIndicatorImage` or `selectedImage` ?

Comment: @Jack setSelectionIndicatorImage

Comment: What's  dimensions of  image ? can you add that?

Comment: @Jack have attached the image

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

> Use selectionIndicatorImage property to specify a custom selection
>   image. Your image is rendered on top of the tab bar but behind the
>   contents of the tab bar item itself. The default value of this
>   property is nil, which causes the tab bar to apply a default highlight
>   to the selected item

If you are using selectionIndicatorImage for certain purpose put this code in `TabBarController class`, here i have use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` because of getting dynamic height of tabbar in both landscape and portrait mode.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print("current height \(tabBar.frame.size.height)")
        let selTab = UIImage(named: "tab1.png")
        let numberOfTabs: CGFloat = 2.0
        let tabSize = CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width)/numberOfTabs, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tabSize);
        selTab?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabSize.width, height: tabSize.height))
        let reSizeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = reSizeImage
    }
```